# Recreate a site from a tcpdump?

Tags: perl, url, extract, tcpdump

It's a long story, but I am trying to save an internal website from the pointy hair bosses who see no value from it anymore and will be flicking the switch at some point in the future. I feel the information contained is important and future generations will want to use it. No, it's not some adult site, but since it's some big corp, I can't say any more.

The problem is, the site is a mess of ASP and Flash that only works under IE7 and is buggy under IE8 and 32bit only even. All the urls are session style and are gibberish. The flash objects itself pull extra information with GET request to ASP objects. It's really poorly designed for scraping. :)

So my idea is to do a tcpdump as I navigate the entire site. Then somehow dump the result of every GET into a sql database. Then with a little messing with the host file, redirect every request to some cgi script that will look for a matching get request in the database and return the data. So the entire site will be located in an SQL database in URL/Data keypairs. Flat file may also work.

In theory, I think this is the only way to go about this. The only problem I see is if they do some client side ActiveX/Flash stuff that generates session URLs that will be different each time.

Anyway, I know Perl, and the idea seems simple with the right modules, so I think I can do most of the work in that, but I am open to any other ideas before I get started. Maybe this exist already?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: ngrep might be better than tcpdump. you can't just abscond with the source?

Comment: Can't you just obtain the code and contents for the site?  Then you can "freeze" it by installing it on a virtual machine that you only run without direct Internet connectivity (the OS would also have to be frozen).

Comment: Find the people who control the site and buy them beer. Become their best friends. Then ask for a database dump.

Comment: Getting access to the source is not likely to happen. I will maybe acquire the drives when the server is decommissioned, if I get the admins dunk enough, but around here, everything is tracked and correctly deposed of when retired. So I don't want to count on it.

Answer (score 2):

To capture I wouldn't use `tcpdump`, but either the crawler itself or a webproxy that can be tweaked to save everything, e.g. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), or [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Interesting idea. Assuming I can set the proxy to save everything. But I am going to be fighting the proxy's natural instinct to keep checking to make sure it's got the latest version, if I use the proxy for playback.

Comment: How well playback works depends on how the site is constructed (how RESTy it is).